# Select value from dataframe based on other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

i try to calculate the position of an object based on a timestamp. For this I have two dataframes in pandas. One for the measurement data and one for the position. All the movement is a straightforward acceleration.

Dataframe 1 contains the measurement data:

```
        ms        force   ...    ...    ...
1      5           20
2      10          20
3      15          25
4      20          30
5      25          20
..... (~ 6000 lines)
```

Dataframe 2 contains "positioning data"

```
        ms        speed (m/s)
1      0           0.66
2      4500        0.66
3      8000        1.3
4      16000       3.0
5      20000       3.0
.....(~300 lines)
```

Now I want to calculate the position of the first dataframe with the data from secound dataframe
In Excel I solved the problem by using an array formular but now I have to use Python/Pandas and I cant find a way how to select the correct row from dataframe 2.

My idea is to make something like this: if

In the end I want to display a graph "force <-> way" and not "force <-> time"

Thank you in andvance

==========================================================================
Update:
In the meantime I could almost solve my issue. Now my Data look like this:

Dataframe 2 (Speed Data):

```
        pos       v         a         t      t-end    t-start
0    -3.000    0.666667  0.000000  4.500000   4.500000   0.000000
1     0.000    0.666667  0.187037  0.071287   4.571287   4.500000
2     0.048    0.680000  0.650794  0.010244   4.581531   4.571287
3     0.055    0.686667  0.205432  0.064904   4.646435   4.581531
...
15    0.055    0.686667  0.5       0.064904     23.0     20.0
...
28    0.055    0.686667  0.6       0.064904     35.0     34.0
...
30    0.055    0.686667  0.9       0.064904     44.0     39.0
```

And Dataframe 1 (time based measurement):

```
        Fx     Fy     Fz      abs_t               expected output ('a' from DF1)
0      -13.9  170.3   45.0   0.005                            0.000000  
1      -14.1  151.6   38.2   0.010                            0.000000  
...
200    -14.1  131.4   30.4   20.015                           0.5
...
300    -14.3  111.9   21.1   34.01                            0.6
...
400    -14.5   95.6   13.2   40.025
```

So i want to check the time(abs_t) from DF1 and search for the corract 'a' in DF2 
So somthing like this (pseudo code):

```
if (DF1['t_abs'] between (DF2['t-start'], DF2['t-end']):
    DF1['a'] = DF2['a']
```

I could make two for loops but it looks like the wrong way and is very very slow.

I hope you understand my problem; to provide a running sample is very hard.
In Excel I did like this:
[image: excel solution]
[image: array formula]

Comment: did you loke at `join`?

Comment: I checked it but maybe i understand it wrong or i don't see the possibility. If i join the two dataframes on the milliseconds i will get something like this:
`
ms    speed    force
0        0.66        NAN
5         NAN         20
10       NAN         20
20       NAN         30
4500  0.66          NAN`

Comment: I don't understand your logic. Can you post expected output?

Comment: can you post code that I can run such that I have examplary dataframes of your format? Have a look at [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: added update on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very slow solution but atleast its working :(

```
df1['a'] = 0
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    start = row['t-start']
    end = row ['t-end']
    a = row ['a']

    df1.loc[(df1['tabs']>start)&(df1['tabs']<end), 'a'] = a
```